# How to update the Owner(standard field) in the custom page using the Referral Id

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula

I need to update owner(Standard Field) name on custom page(Buyer) using Referral Id(mobile of Lead owner)..

The Referral Id(Mobile No) already present in user details.

For example the buyer is created by me but i put the Referral Id was my manager mobile no.After created the Buyer i need to updated owner as my manager name not mine.Now it show my name.

I tried the following trigger

```
trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger on Broker__c (after insert,after update) 
{
    List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();

    for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
    {     
      if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
      {
          // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
          List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                   where MobilePhone= :broker.Referral_ID__c ];

          // if you found one
          if (zip.size() > 0) 
          {    
              //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
              broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 

              leadsToUpdate.add(broker);

          }
       } 

     }

      // update the records
      try 
      {
           insert leadsToUpdate;
      }
      catch (DmlException dm)
      {

      }     
}
```

I got the Following  Error

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: LeadAssignmentTrigger:
>   execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is
>   read-only: Trigger.LeadAssignmentTrigger: line 17, column 1

Comment: why you are inserting record.. Just change the after insert and after update to before insert and before update... and remove last insert statement .. Everything will work fine

Comment: Thanks Ratan. Ya its working fine. But some time user enter the mobile with +91.But in my referral id i have without +91 mobile no. Now how i match.

Comment: Ask a new question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed all the fields and object names and wrote the code. It would be better if you can share the clear names.

**Bulkified trigger solution:**

```
    trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger on Broker__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();

    for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
    {     
      if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
      {
          // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
          List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                   where MobilePhone= :broker.Referral_ID__c ];

          // if you found one
          if (zip.size() > 0) 
          {    
              //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
              broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 

              leadsToUpdate.add(broker);

          }
       } 

     }

      // update the records

}
```

Comment: the custom page name is called Buyers and the Referral Id (mobile no of Lead Owner).The Referral id was already present in user details,then i update the referral id name in the custom page. Now it so the buyer name but i need the referral name for the lead

Comment: I modify the account was Customer/Lead Page